# RESTful API Design - same path diffrent roles

Tags: c#, api, rest, azure-active-directory, roles

I´m currently working on a RESTful API, which has to give access to two diffrent Roles: Admin and User. (I'm wokring with Azure AD App Roles)
My Problem is that I don't understand how I can design the controller logic.
For example I want both (admin and user) to access the endpoint /books, but the admin is allowed to see all books and the user is only allowed to see his books.
What is the best practice to give both the allowed access? I thought of splitting it into two enpoints like this:

```cs
/books -> with annotation [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
/user/{id}/books -> with annotation [Authorize(Roles="User")]
```

Thanks for helping!

Best regards

Comment: That sounds like a sensible approach - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/blob/main/3-Authorization-II/groups/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azuresamples/msal4j/msidentityspringbootwebapp/SampleController.java) may be of some help. And if you need sample written by other languages, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications) to find a suitable one.

And on your case, I think the most important thing is to find out the way to execute the right query and make the query result return to correct user.

So if you set a specific url for each user(I don't think this a good idea to expose user id in the request link), or you hide the user role/id into the token which contained in request header, you all need to write logic code to check which query method need to run. For example, hit domain:port/books with an access token, then your filter catch this request and decode the token to know the user id and user role, and maybe can save them in the session, then your controller may check the value stored in session and choose a right query to get the books information.